# Add support for EPSG:2065 and EPSG:5514 in deegree

Tags: coordinate-system, deegree

I would like to add support for EPSG:2065 and EPSG:5514 in deegree.

[EPSG:2065](https://epsg.org/crs_2065/S-JTSK-Ferro-Krovak.html?sessionkey=u7y86db6m2)

[EPSG:5514](https://epsg.org/crs_5514/S-JTSK-Krovak-East-North.html?sessionkey=yex7vcnsr8)

I manually created the deegree crs configuration files based on viewing existing configuration examples. I cannot find any documentation on how to create the files.

My datasets publish, however they are not displaying correctly.

CONFIGURATION FILES EPSG:5514

Added to ..datum-definitions.xml

```
<crs:GeodeticDatum>
    <crs:Id>epsg:6156</crs:Id>
    <crs:Name>System of the Unified Trigonometrical Cadastral Network</crs:Name>
    <crs:Version>2018-02-16 ChangeID 2017.037</crs:Version>
    <crs:UsedEllipsoid>epsg:7004</crs:UsedEllipsoid>
    <crs:UsedPrimeMeridian>urn:opengis:def:crs:epsg::8901</crs:UsedPrimeMeridian>
</crs:GeodeticDatum>
```

Added to ..crs-defintions.xml

```
<crs:GeographicCRS>
    <crs:Id>epsg:4156</crs:Id>
    <crs:Id>http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4156</crs:Id>
    <crs:Id>urn:ogc:def:crs:epsg::4156</crs:Id>
    <crs:Id>urn:opengis:def:crs:epsg::4156</crs:Id>
    <crs:Name>S-JTSK</crs:Name>
    <crs:Version>2018-02-16 ChangeID 2017.037</crs:Version>
    <crs:Description>Handmade proj4 geographic crs definition (parsed from nad/epsg).</crs:Description>
    <crs:AreaOfUse>12.09,47.73,22.56,51.06</crs:AreaOfUse>
    <crs:AreaOfUse>Czech Republic; Slovakia.</crs:AreaOfUse>
    <crs:Axis>
        <crs:Name>latitude</crs:Name>
        <crs:Units>degree</crs:Units>
        <crs:AxisOrientation>north</crs:AxisOrientation>
    </crs:Axis>
    <crs:Axis>
        <crs:Name>longitude</crs:Name>
        <crs:Units>degree</crs:Units>
        <crs:AxisOrientation>east</crs:AxisOrientation>
    </crs:Axis>
    <crs:UsedDatum>epsg:6156</crs:UsedDatum>
</crs:GeographicCRS>

<crs:ProjectedCRS>
    <crs:Id>epsg:5514</crs:Id>
    <crs:Id>http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#5514</crs:Id>
    <crs:Id>urn:ogc:def:crs:epsg::5514</crs:Id>
    <crs:Id>urn:opengis:def:crs:epsg::5514</crs:Id>
    <crs:Name>S-JTSK / Krovak East North</crs:Name>
    <crs:Version>2018-02-16 ChangeID 2017.037</crs:Version>
    <crs:AreaOfUse>12.09,47.73,22.56,51.06</crs:AreaOfUse>
    <crs:AreaOfUse>Czech Republic; Slovakia.</crs:AreaOfUse>
    <crs:Axis>
            <crs:Name>x</crs:Name>
            <crs:Units>metre</crs:Units>
            <crs:AxisOrientation>east</crs:AxisOrientation>
    </crs:Axis>
    <crs:Axis>
            <crs:Name>y</crs:Name>
            <crs:Units>metre</crs:Units>
            <crs:AxisOrientation>north</crs:AxisOrientation>
    </crs:Axis>
    <crs:UsedGeographicCRS>epsg:4156</crs:UsedGeographicCRS>
    <crs:UsedProjection>epsg:5510</crs:UsedProjection>
</crs:ProjectedCRS>
```

Added to ..projection-definitions.xml

```
<crs:TransverseMercator>
    <crs:Id>epsg:5510</crs:Id>
    <crs:Name>Krovak East North (Greenwich)</crs:Name>
    <crs:LatitudeOfNaturalOrigin>49.5</crs:LatitudeOfNaturalOrigin>
    <crs:LongitudeOfNaturalOrigin>24.8333333333333</crs:LongitudeOfNaturalOrigin>
    <crs:ScaleFactor>0.9999</crs:ScaleFactor>
    <crs:FalseEasting>0</crs:FalseEasting>
    <crs:FalseNorthing>0</crs:FalseNorthing>
</crs:TransverseMercator>
```

CONFIGURATION FILES EPSG:2065

Added to ..datum-definitions.xml

```
<crs:GeodeticDatum>
    <crs:Id>epsg:6818</crs:Id>
    <crs:Name>System of the Unified Trigonometrical Cadastral Network (Ferro)</crs:Name>
    <crs:Version>2018-02-16 ChangeID 2017.037</crs:Version>
    <crs:UsedEllipsoid>epsg:7004</crs:UsedEllipsoid>
    <crs:UsedPrimeMeridian>urn:opengis:def:crs:epsg::8909</crs:UsedPrimeMeridian>
</crs:GeodeticDatum>
```

Added to ..crs-definitions.xml

```
<crs:GeographicCRS>
    <crs:Id>epsg:4818</crs:Id>
    <crs:Id>http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4818</crs:Id>
    <crs:Id>urn:ogc:def:crs:epsg::4818</crs:Id>
    <crs:Id>urn:opengis:def:crs:epsg::4818</crs:Id>
    <crs:Name>S-JTSK (Ferro)</crs:Name>
    <crs:Version>2018-02-16 ChangeID 2017.037</crs:Version>
    <crs:Description>Handmade proj4 geographic crs definition (parsed from nad/epsg).</crs:Description>
    <crs:AreaOfUse>12.09,47.73,22.56,51.06</crs:AreaOfUse>
    <crs:AreaOfUse>Czech Republic; Slovakia.</crs:AreaOfUse>
    <crs:Axis>
        <crs:Name>latitude</crs:Name>
        <crs:Units>degree</crs:Units>
        <crs:AxisOrientation>north</crs:AxisOrientation>
    </crs:Axis>
    <crs:Axis>
        <crs:Name>longitude</crs:Name>
        <crs:Units>degree</crs:Units>
        <crs:AxisOrientation>east</crs:AxisOrientation>
    </crs:Axis>
    <crs:UsedDatum>epsg:6818</crs:UsedDatum>
</crs:GeographicCRS>

<crs:ProjectedCRS>
    <crs:Id>epsg:2065</crs:Id>
    <crs:Id>http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#2065</crs:Id>
    <crs:Id>urn:ogc:def:crs:epsg::2065</crs:Id>
    <crs:Id>urn:opengis:def:crs:epsg::2065</crs:Id>
    <crs:Name>S-JTSK (Ferro) / Krovak</crs:Name>
    <crs:Version>2018-02-16 ChangeID 2017.037</crs:Version>
    <crs:AreaOfUse>12.09,47.73,22.56,51.06</crs:AreaOfUse>
    <crs:AreaOfUse>Czech Republic; Slovakia.</crs:AreaOfUse>
    <crs:Axis>
            <crs:Name>x</crs:Name>
            <crs:Units>metre</crs:Units>
            <crs:AxisOrientation>south</crs:AxisOrientation>
    </crs:Axis>
    <crs:Axis>
            <crs:Name>y</crs:Name>
            <crs:Units>metre</crs:Units>
            <crs:AxisOrientation>west</crs:AxisOrientation>
    </crs:Axis>
    <crs:UsedGeographicCRS>epsg:4818</crs:UsedGeographicCRS>
    <crs:UsedProjection>epsg:19952</crs:UsedProjection>
</crs:ProjectedCRS>
```

Added to ..projection-definitions.xml

```
<crs:TransverseMercator>
    <crs:Id>epsg:19952</crs:Id>
    <crs:Name>Krovak</crs:Name>
    <crs:LatitudeOfNaturalOrigin>49.5</crs:LatitudeOfNaturalOrigin>
    <crs:LongitudeOfNaturalOrigin>42.5</crs:LongitudeOfNaturalOrigin>
    <crs:ScaleFactor>0.9999</crs:ScaleFactor>
    <crs:FalseEasting>0</crs:FalseEasting>
    <crs:FalseNorthing>0</crs:FalseNorthing>
</crs:TransverseMercator>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Kind regards,
Kate

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what software are you using>

Comment: I am using deegree- it's a webserver.

Comment: And it's here http://www.deegree.org/. It's German and it explains the joke in the product name.

Comment: `The CRS subsystem is not fully integrated with the deegree workspace yet. Rework and proper documentation are on the roadmap for one of the next releases. If you have trouble finding a specific CRS, please contact the deegree mailing lists for support.`

Comment: @nmtoken Unfortunately I cannot join the mailing list. My email is rejected by the list and the list's admin contact's email.

Comment: for documentation on how to create/amend the files see the schema `http://schemas.deegree.org/3.5/crs/crsdefinition.xsd.`

Comment: for `epsg:2065` the names should be `Southing` and `Westing` and for epsg:5514 they should be `Easting` and `Northing`